# How to change Spring Social JdbcUsersConnectionRepository table name and column names?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-social

I'm using *spring social authentication* in a *spring boot* application. To persist the social user details I'm trying to use *mysql* with `JdbcUsersConnectionRepository`.

I need to change the table name which is by default set to `prefix + UserConnect`. The table name and all the column names are in camel naming convention. But in my application, database columns are in underscore naming convention.

When I checked the sourcecode of `JdbcUsersConnectionRepository` it's hard coded like below

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select userId from " + tablePrefix + "UserConnection where providerId = ? and provide....
```

I know i can rewrite the `UsersConnectionRepository` implementation and do this. Which is actually i'm doing at the moment.

```
public class SecUsersConnectionRepository implements UsersConnectionRepository {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private UserConnectionRepository userConnectionRepository;
    private ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator;

.....
.....
```

But in this way i have to rewrite the same logic in `JdbcUsersConnectionRepository` again. Which is not productive at all. So what is the best practice to achieve this?

I hope I'm not the only one who faces such issue with spring social. Please share your knowledge on how you solve such situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible I'm afraid because, as you rightly pointed out, it's hardcoded in Spring code.

Check the official response
[Spring forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/social/130545-can-you-modify-or-change-userconnection-table-in-spring-social-showcase)

If you don't want to replicate code, you must stick to spring's default table name. This is what I did in my project.

Cheers.

Comment: You are right. It's a pity why spring don't make those values changeable without rewriting the logic. I actually rewrote my own classes for this.

Comment: Yeah this is maddening. Why would they go against their own standard table naming convention and screw everyone over with the stupid camel-case db table naming. #FAIL